# Join a table with results of function for each value of table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that consists of several Id's like this

```
SELECT * FROM Objects;

ObjectId
---------
    1
    4
    5
```

and function that produce another table for each ObjectId, for instance

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.GetNumbers(1)        SELECT * FROM dbo.GetNumbers(4)       SELECT * FROM dbo.GetNumbers(5) 

NumberId                               NumberId                              NumberId
---------                              ---------                             ---------
    40                                     11                                    12
    45                                     2                                    
                                           18
```

How can I get the cartesian product of original table with the tables produced by functions **without using cursors**?

```
    SELECT ???

    ObjectId    NumberId
    ---------------------
        1           40
        1           45
        4           11
        4           2
        4           18
        5           12
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Why is that a cartesian product?

Comment: @Jodrell sure, it's not a cartesian product but something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you just want to [do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)?

```
SELECT
              o.ObjectId
            , n.NumberId
   FROM
            Objects o
       CROSS APPLY
            dbo.GetNumbers(o.ObjectId) n
```

If you want to include `Objects` that have no `GetNumbers` results use `OUTER APPLY`.

A simple way of looking at it is, [`CROSS APPLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is an [`INNER JOIN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to a [TVF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), [`OUTER APPLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is a [`LEFT OUTER JOIN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to a [TVF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

You shouldn't confuse these with [`CROSS JOIN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) which has nothing specific to do with functions and is used to provide the [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of two sets, which is not what you want here.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by `dbo.` this might be Sql Server in which case [outer apply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) might help:

```
select objects.ObjectID,
       numbers.NumberID
  from objects
 outer apply 
 (
   SELECT * 
     FROM dbo.GetNumbers(objects.objectid)
 ) numbers
```